# Homeomorphism between positive rationals and non-negative rationals

Tags: general-topology

Professor told me the two spaces are homeomorphic if we consider them as subspaces of R equipped with the standard topology.

It's a bit surprising for me since I have already found Q is homeomorphic to the positive rationals and I know that the two spaces in the main question are homeomorphic, so how can the positive rationals and non-negative rationals be homeomorphic?

Comment: It must have edited itself, I want a homeomorphism from the positive rationals to the non-negative rationals

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119022/homeomorphism-between-mathbbq-and-mathbbq0-and-mathbbq-ge-0?rq=1